# MsgBox closes form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0

In my program (form1) i call another form (form3) with `Form3.ShowDialog()`. This form runs a relativly long process that is tracked by a progress bar. In this form there is a button to cancel this process(generate pdf document) and revert the process.

The code for the cancel button (form3) is as follows:

```
Private Sub annulerBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles annulerBtn.Click
        If (MsgBox("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir annuler? Cette reviendra toutes les modifications apportées au document", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "annuler l'exportation") = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then

            _cancel = True

            doc.Close()       'close pdf'
            fs.Close()        'close stream'

            If (_done And _backup) Or (Not _done And _backup) Then

                'revert file from backup if backup exists'
                System.IO.File.Delete(_path)
                IO.File.Copy("C:\temp\temp.pdf", _path)
                IO.File.Delete("C:\temp\temp.pdf")

            Else

                'otherwise simply delete the new file'
                System.IO.File.Delete(_path)

            End If

            Me.Close()
        Else
            'continue with the form!!'
        End If
    End Sub
```

I would like this button to end the process and revert changes using the backup.

I am currently staying away from multithreading and im using an `Application.DoEvents()` inside the process to continue taking user input.

If the user presses the yes button, the function works as expected. However if the user presses no, the process will continue as expected, but the form will close afterwards!

Debugging shows that it it never calls `Me.Close()` or `Form3.Close()` after the user presses no.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated, Thank you!

**EDIT:** Here is the call stack

```
    App58.exe!App58.Form3.Form3_FormClosing(Object sender = {App58.Form3}, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs}) Line 432  Basic
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) + 0x77 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckCloseDialog(bool closingOnly = false) + 0x8c bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FContinueMessageLoop(int reason, int pvLoopData, System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG[] msgPeeked) + 0x160 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(int dwComponentID, int reason = 4, int pvLoopData = 0) + 0x1ae bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = 4, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.Application.ModalApplicationContext}) + 0x177 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form form) + 0x33 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x370 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() + 0x7 bytes 
    App58.exe!App58.Form1.RB_pdf_Click(Object sender = {Text = "Exporter PDF"}, System.EventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs}) Line 1994 + 0xa bytes   Basic
```

Comment: not clear what you want, I don't think it's such difficult to express the problem, What is this `the form as it is supposed to`? and the `form` is referred to what? ... please try rephrasing your problem.

Comment: You commented out the code that matters most.  A basic debugging strategy is to add the FormClosing event handler and set a breakpoint on it.  Look at the call stack to see how it got there.

Comment: So you want it to call `Me.Close()` even if the user presses no?

Comment: @Douglas Barbin No, this is what i'm desperately trying to avoid. The form closes when the user chooses the "no" option

Comment: Just as a generic warning, I'd stay away from the legacy MsgBox().  I've seen numerous weird "bugs" that went away when the proper MessageBox.Show() was used instead.

Comment: this problem would be able to debug easily. It's strange that the `Form3.annulerBtn_Click` is not present in the `stack trace`, as described, it's the origin causing the unexpected form closing (after user selecting `No`). You didn't post any code in the outermost `Else ... End If` which is the code part run when user selects `No`, just set a break point there at the outermost `Else ...` and the bug should be discovered.

Comment: There is no code in the else statement when it produces this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild guess, you tell me if it is right.

the property [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) for the button `annulerBtn` is set to something different from [`None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx).
Or the property [`CancelButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) or [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the form3 is set to the `annulerBtn`

If one of this conditions is true, then your form will close itself automatically when you click that button, regardless of your calling the `Close` method or not. If you want to stop this chain of events you should set the `form3.DialogResult` property to `DialogResult.None` before exiting the click event. (Or remove the association between the form and the button setup by the properties above)